# Bounding $I(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^2\exp(t)}{2}\mathrm dt$

Tags: integration

Suppose $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $I(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{(x-t)^2\exp(t)}{2}\,\mathrm dt}$.

Without calculating $I(x)$ how can I prove that:

- $\forall x \ge 0$, $\quad0\le I(x) \le \dfrac{\exp(x)x^3}{6}$;
- $\forall x\le0$, $\quad |I(x)|\le \dfrac{|x|^3}{6}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: $\exp(t)$ is an increasing function for $0<t<x$ for any $x \geq 0$, thus
$$
   |I(x)| = \left| \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} \exp(t) \mathrm{d}t \right| \leqslant  \left| \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} \exp(x) \mathrm{d}t \right| = \exp(x) \left| \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} \mathrm{d}t \right|
$$
You should be able to finish it off now

Answer (score 3):

Just note that

$$ I(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{(x-t)^2\exp(t)}{2}dt}=\int_{0}^{x}{\dfrac{(t)^2\exp(x-t)}{2}dt}\longrightarrow (1) $$

$$ \implies |I(x)|\leq \frac{e^x}{2}\int_{0}^{x}t^2 dt =\dots,$$

since $e^{-t}\leq 1 $ on the interval $[0,x]$.

**Added:** Eq. $(1)$ follows from the property of the convolution

$$ \int_{0}^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)g(x-t)dt. $$